# Outlets not working in laundry room. GFCI nonreactive. What should I do?

Tags: electrical, gfci

The washer in laundry room was working fine.  Then it quit working.  Anything plugged into any of the outlets in the laundry room do not work.  Went I put a voltage detector in the outlet it tells me there is voltage.  The breaker is not tripped.

There is a GFCI in the laundry room and when I press "test" or "reset" nothing happens.

But that does not explain why the other outlets in laundry room do not work.

Help please.

Comment: Are there any other GFCI outlets on this circuit? I had one in basement bathroom that tripped an outside outlet.

Comment: What kind of voltage detector did you use?  Was it a three-prong unit with 3 LEDs?  That is the kind you need.  If it was just a single probe you are probably getting a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Other outlets may be connected to **load** terminals of GFCI's - and depending on your layout, that may not be the one in the laundry room. Or it may be the one in the laundry room, and its failure to reset either means there is a fault, or that it has failed. If anything is plugged in to any of the outlets, try unplugging it before you try resetting again.

It is certainly possible (not what I would do, but possible) to have two GFCIs where one is fed from the load terminals of another, and the other is not in an "obvious" location to the items disabled by it.

It's often worth switching the correct breaker manually "off" and back on, as trips are not always as obvious as we would hope.